# Unable to navigate to route with ID in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-routing

I am unable to navigate to route with ID argument when using router.

Using this code inside my component

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
...
constructor(private router: Router) { }
...
public create() {
    ...
    this.router.navigate(['/category/edit', id]);
}
```

leads to an error

```
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'category/edit;id=11'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:1719)
    at CatchSubscriber.eval [as selector] (router.js:1684)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:105)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:131)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:105)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:131)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:105)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:131)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:105)
    at LastSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:131)
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:1719)
    at CatchSubscriber.eval [as selector] (router.js:1684)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:105)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:131)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:105)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:131)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:105)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:131)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:105)
    at LastSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:131)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:809)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:775)
    at eval (zone.js:858)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4724)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:500)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1517)
```

If using it inside the template it work fine

```html
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let category of model">
        <td>{{category.name}}</td>
        <td>{{category.code}}</td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" [routerLink]="['/category/edit', category.id]">Edit</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This is my route definition

```
{
    path: 'category/edit/:id',
    component: EditComponent,
    resolve: {
        model: CategoryResolver
    }
}
```

Tried it with and without the resolver but it does not work either way.

I am using **Angular 5.2.0** and **CLI 1.6.5**

Comment: Do you have a simple typo somewhere? The URL is `category/edit;id=11`, but that won't match the route definition `category/edit/:id` as there's no forward slash after `edit` in the URL.

Comment: what console.log of id just before this.router.navigate(['.. gives?

Comment: @Brandon If using `['category/edit', category.id]` from the template it works. It does not work if using router to navigate. When I change the navigation to `this.router.navigate(['category/edit/:id', id])` it does work. But then my new browser location is like '../category/edit/:id;id=11'.

Comment: @Vega Console output is {id: 13}. Seems like it's not what I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `this.router.navigate(['/category/edit', id]);` is `category/edit;id=11`. Query params (as `;id=11`) are used, when you pass in an object instead of a string. I suppose that your variable `id` is of type object instead of string.

```js
id: Object = {id: '11'};
```

should be changed to

```js
id: string = '11';
```

Comment: I was expecting an Observable<number> but the the actual value was an object { id: 11 }. Changed my code like you suggested and now it works!